# Cffi : avoid duplicate declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cffi

I start to use cffi in a big project, with many file import.
As I use structure, I have many structure declaration like this :

```
ffi.cdef("""
typedef struct sMyStruct
  {
    int32_t  nbData;
    int32_t  nbMaxData;
  } tMyStruct;
""")
```

As I have multiple inter depencies, multiple import, I have sometime :

```
cffi.error.CDefError: <cdef source string>:6: duplicate declaration of struct sMyStruct
```

I am looking for some good pratice to avoid this.

Set a clean interdepencies, set only necessary import in the right place is not a realist solution for my case.

My first idea is :

```
try:
  ffi.cdef("""
  typedef struct sMyStruct
  {
    int32_t  nbData;
    int32_t  nbMaxData;
  } tMyStruct;
  """)
except cffi.error.CDefError as e:
        if e.args[0].startswith("duplicate declaration"):
            pass
        else:
            raise e
except:
        raise
```

It's, but I think we can do better.

What could be a better suggestion ?

Comment: For a big project, using the out-of-line mode of cffi would be better, also because it won't be so slow to import all your project when you start it.  The out-of-line mode forces you to think about declarations in a more structured and C-like way, which should avoid these issues.

Comment: Thanks, I have start read http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html about out-of-line mode. I need some time to find good solution for my project, but it seems a good way.